# Formal substitution of exponential factors in an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

Assume that we have some complex algebraic expression, like

```
Exp[(a t + b s)/w] ( t Exp[ q t] w + q Exp[q s] Exp[-2 s] + a^2 Exp[3 s] + s t + 1 )
```

Now, this is just an example, the form of the expression is not very important. What is important is that we want to understand which is the exponential dependence on

```
Exp[s] and Exp[t]
```

by using some symbols, say `es` and `et`, as placeholders for `Exp[s]` and `Exp[t]`.

In practice, I'd like to rearrange it to obtain (formally):

```
et^(a/w) es^(b/w) ( t et^q w + q es^(q-2) + a^2 es^3 + s t + 1 )
```

Note that I can not use the substitution `/.{t -> Log[et]}` because   `t` and `s` also appear outside the exponential functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Exp[(a t + b s)/w] (t Exp[q t] w + q Exp[q s] Exp[-2 s] + 
     a^2 Exp[3 s] + s t + 1);

expr //. {Exp[c_. (a_. s + b_.)] :> es^(a*c)*Exp[b*c], 
  Exp[c_. (a_. t + b_.)] :> et^(a*c)*Exp[b*c]}

(* es^(b/w) et^(a/w) (1 + a^2 es^3 + es^(-2 + q) q + s t + et^q t w) *)
```

Note that the first factor is `es^(b/w)` **NOT** (as you showed) `es^(a/w)`

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the typo!

Answer (score 3):

Another workable solution that uses your idea of using `Log`:

```
expr /. Exp[a_] :> Simplify@Exp[Expand@a /. {t -> Log[et], s -> Log[es]}]
```

Wrap it up into a function where you specify the variables:

```
f[expr_, vars_List] := expr /. Exp[a_] :> Simplify@Exp[Expand@a /. Thread[vars -> Log[Symbol["e" <> ToString[#]] & /@ vars]]]
```

Then:

```
expr = Exp[(a t + b s)/w] ( t Exp[ q t] w + q Exp[q s] Exp[-2 s] + a^2 Exp[3 s] + s t + 1 );
f[expr, {s, t}]
(* es^(b/w) et^(a/w) (1 + a^2 es^3 + es^(-2 + q) q + s t + et^q t w) *)
```

Although, I prefer to index variables, so I would use

```
f[expr_, vars_List] := expr /. Exp[a_] :> Simplify@Exp[Expand@a /. Thread[vars -> Log[e /@ vars]]]
```

instead.